# c++-to-python swig caused memory leak! Related to Py_BuildValue and SWIG_NewPointerObj

Tags: python, swig

I have the following Swig code that caused memory leak.

```
  PyObject* FindBestMatch(const Bar& fp) {
    Foo* ptr(new Foo());
    float match;

    // call a function to fill the foo pointer

    return Py_BuildValue(
        "(fO)",
        match,
        SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr,
                           SWIGTYPE_p_Foo,
                           0 /* own */));
  }
```

I figured that ptr is not freed properly. So I did the following:

```
  PyObject* FindBestMatch(const Bar& fp) {
    Foo* ptr(new Foo());
    float match;

    // call a function to fill the foo pointer

    *PyObject *o = SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr,
                       SWIGTYPE_p_Foo,
                       1 /* own */);*  <------- 1 means pass the ownership to python
    PyObject *result = Py_BuildValue("(fO)", match, o);
    Py_XDECREF(o);
    return result;
  }
```

But I am not very sure whether this will cause memory corruption. Here,         Py_XDECREF(o) will decrease the ref count, which can free memory used by object "o". But o is part of the return value "result". Freeing "o" can cause data corrupt, I guess?

I tried my change. It works fine and the caller (python code) does see the expected data. But this could be because nobody else overwrites to that memory area.

So what's the right way to deal with memory management of the above code? I search the swig docs, but don't see very concrete description.

Please help!

Thanks,
xin

Comment: Having a similar issue with the python-nfqueue-bindings code is here http://git.inl.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=nfqueue-bindings.git;a=blob;f=python/libnetfilter_queue_python.i;h=fa077b74d1f9a9cbc801c2ff276a98153a0a5734;hb=09b4ad6092195d5f59b713e26ea61e8ef9f19b7d

Comment: I have run into similar memory leak problems with the SWIG python code - its one of the reasons we stopped using SWIG in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the code automatically generated by SWIG for function that allocate a new object, the proper way should be to just set the Python Ownership flag to one, which means : **python owns this pointer**
This make sense : where else could your `new Foo()` be deallocated ? The Swig wrapper object will handle it.

```
PyObject* FindBestMatch(const Bar& fp) {
    Foo* ptr(new Foo());
    float match;

    // call a function to fill the foo pointer

    PyObject* o = SWIG_NewPointerObj(ptr,
                   SWIGTYPE_p_Foo,
                   SWIG_BUILTIN_INIT |  0);

    PyObject* result = Py_BuildValue("(fO)", match, o);
    return result;
}
```

However I don't see why you would decrease the reference count on o : if I recall correctly when passing an object to a tuple or list the reference is stolen.